# Jenkinsfile / bash : syntax error

Tags: bash, jenkins

I'm trying to execute this following Jenkinsfile command to delete everything except the `foobar` folder :

```
node {
    stage('Clean') {
        sh 'rm -rf ./path/to/folder/!(foobar)'
    }
}
```

But I get the following error :

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Why I'm getting this error

Answer (score 1):

`!(foobar)` works in `bash`, not in `sh`; still this is what [`sh` in Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) does:

> Runs a Bourne shell script, typically on a Unix node. […] the system default shell will be run, using the `-xe` flags

So it uses `sh` rather than `bash`. The command allows you to use a shebang though. I believe this will make your command be interpreted by Bash (adjust the shebang if necessary):

```
sh '''#!/bin/bash
      rm -rf ./path/to/folder/!(foobar)
   '''
```